# Summerize two if statements in one

Tags: java

I have many `if` and `if else` statement as in the code below. Is it possiable to summerize the

```
 if (zob.equals(""))
```

and

```
else if (!(nameShortestDistance.equals("ABC")) 
    && !(nameShortestDistance.equals("DEF")))
```

statement in one if statement condition?

**Code:**

```
if (zob.equals("")) {
    int stops_number = number_stop_in_table(macD, con);
    if (stops_number > 2) {
        Analyzer analyzer = new Analyzer(host, user, password);
        analyzer.analyze_data();
        System.out.println("Result: " + stops_number);
    }
    maintain_records(speedD, macD, con,
            shortestDistance, nameShortestDistance,
            sto_nam);
} else if (!(nameShortestDistance
        .equals("ABC"))
        && !(nameShortestDistance
                .equals("DEF"))) {
    int stops_number = number_stop_in_table(macD, con);
    if (stops_number > 2) {
        Analyzer analyzer = new Analyzer(host, user, password);
        analyzer.analyze_data();
        System.out.println("Result: "+ stops_number);
    }
    maintain_records(speedD, macD, con, shortestDistance, 
        nameShortestDistance, sto_nam);
}
```

Comment: just do it with conditional or operator

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. It's called the "[conditional OR operator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.24)" (aka the "logical OR operator"), `||`.

```
if (a || b) {
    // We get here if either operand is true
)
```

There's a tutorial about them [here on the Oracle website](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op2.html).

Answer (score 2):

I would perhaps consider refactoring this completely such that you have methods for your tests, and then give those methods meaningful names. Rather than have one sizable method with conditionals on primitive fields, you could have something like:

```
if (isSuchAndSuchPopulated() && isShortestDistance()) {
   ...
}
```

Consequently your method becomes shorter and (hopefully) more readable. Furthermore, if those methods are exposed, then you can unit test them individually, which makes life simpler

Comment: Readability is the most important aspect of any code.

Answer (score 0):

This might help. List of different kinds of operators. Using these, your options are endless... Take some time learning those...

Copied from https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/opsummary.html

> ```
> Simple Assignment Operator
>
> =       Simple assignment operator
> Arithmetic Operators
>
> +       Additive operator (also used
>         for String concatenation)
> -       Subtraction operator
> *       Multiplication operator
> /       Division operator
> %       Remainder operator
> Unary Operators
>
> +       Unary plus operator; indicates
>         positive value (numbers are 
>         positive without this, however)
> -       Unary minus operator; negates
>         an expression
> ++      Increment operator; increments
>         a value by 1
> --      Decrement operator; decrements
>         a value by 1
> !       Logical complement operator;
>         inverts the value of a boolean
> Equality and Relational Operators
>
> ==      Equal to
> !=      Not equal to
> >       Greater than
> >=      Greater than or equal to
> <       Less than
> <=      Less than or equal to 
> Conditional Operators
>
> &&      Conditional-AND
> ||      Conditional-OR
> ?:      Ternary (shorthand for 
>         if-then-else statement)
> Type Comparison Operator
>
> instanceof      Compares an object to a specified type 
> Bitwise and Bit Shift Operators
>
> ~       Unary bitwise complement
> <<      Signed left shift
> >>      Signed right shift
> >>>     Unsigned right shift
> &       Bitwise AND
> ^       Bitwise exclusive OR
> |       Bitwise inclusive OR
> ```